# How to create factor with mutate with levels coming from another col

Tags: r, dplyr, factors, mutate

I have this df:

| city | code |
| --- | --- |
| PR | 41 |
| SC | 42 |
| RS | 43 |

I want to change city to factor, but keep the order as in the code. If I only do

```
df %>% mutate(city= factor(city))
```

it orders alphabetically.

I would like something such as

```
df %>% mutate(city= factor(city, levels = code))
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I don't want to do manually `levels = c('PR', 'SC', 'RS')` because it has many more categories!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `levels = unique(city))` as `unique` gets the unique elements in the order of occurrence of the elements

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
     mutate(city = factor(city, levels = unique(city)))
```

---

If we want to reorder based on a different column, use `fct_reorder`

```
library(forcats)
df <- df %>%
    mutate(city = fct_reorder(city, code))
```

-checking

```
levels(df$city)
[1] "PR" "SC" "RS"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(city = c("PR", "SC", "RS"), code = 41:43), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: You are too fast!:-)

Comment: Thanks! but do you know if there is a way to order it by the other col? I feel more safe doing it by the codes!